# lmerControl(calc.derivs) argument in lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a huge dataframe (31584 rows) which consists of crop yield data collected over multiple districts and years.

Each district is nested within a State and each State is nested within an ACZ or climate zone. I want to build a mixed model using yield as response and 11 climate variables (one of which is a drought index). I also have another grouping variable which classifies the irrigation level as low, medium or high.

I specified my model as follows:

```
 mod <- lmer(crop.yield ~ # 11 climate variables + (1|ACZ) + (1|state) + (1 + year|district) +  (1 + drought|irrigation), REML = FALSE, data = dat, control = lmerControl(optCtrl = list(maxfun = 10000000))
```

It's been four hours and the model is still running.  I am reading this vignette

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmerperf.html

which says

`use control = [g]lmerControl(calc.derivs = FALSE) to turn off the time consuming derivative calculation that is performed after the optmization is finished, e.g.`

I wanted some advise whether it is safe to switch it off and what implications does it have on the overall model fitting?